# I have animated left and right character how could I animate my right and left standing without it blitting all at the same time?

Tags: python, pygame

so I animated my character if I am going right blit this if I am going left blit this BUT
how do I make it so when I am not moving right to blit my right standing animation and  the left?

> I managed to do it for my right side but idk why my left side isnt working [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/36047e28809e64e3bd68fe81be351376)

```
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        if self.direction == "left":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            player_image = self.lefts[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.lefts):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction != "left":
            player_image = self.standingleft[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standingleft):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.direction == "right":
            player_image = self.rights[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.rights):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "standright":
            player_image = self.standingright[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standingright):
                self.anim_index = 0
```

My player class

```
# player class

class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.height  = height
        self.width = width
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        #hit box
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)
        self.stand = pygame.image.load("stands.png")
        self.rights = [pygame.image.load("L1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L5.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L6.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L7.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L8.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L9.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L10.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L11.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L12.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L13.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L14.png"),
        pygame.image.load("L15.png")]
        self.fps = 50
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.lefts = [pygame.image.load("e1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e5.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e6.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e7.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e8.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e9.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e10.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e11.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e12.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e13.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e14.png"),
        pygame.image.load("e15.png")]
        self.standingright = [pygame.image.load("d1.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d2.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d3.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d4.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d5.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d6.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d7.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d8.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d9.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d10.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d11.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d12.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d13.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d14.png"),
                pygame.image.load("d15.png")]
        self.standingleft =[pygame.image.load("s1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s5.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s6.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s7.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s8.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s9.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s10.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s11.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s12.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s13.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s14.png"),
            pygame.image.load("s15.png")]
        self.rights = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.rights]
        self.lefts = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.lefts]
        self.standingright = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.standingright]
        self.standingleft = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//5,image.get_height()//5)) for image in self.standingleft]
        self.bo_index = 0
        self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.anim_fps = 400
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.stans_index = 0
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.direction = "standright"

        self.rect = pygame.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width, height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

        if self.direction == "left":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            player_image = self.lefts[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.lefts):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction != "left":
            player_image = self.standingleft[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standingleft):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.direction == "right":
            player_image = self.rights[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.rights):
                self.anim_index = 0
        elif self.direction == "standright":
            player_image = self.standingright[self.anim_index]
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.standingright):
                self.anim_index = 0
```

Comment: The issue is not related to this code. Where do you set `self.direction`?

Comment: on my player left and right key behinds https://gyazo.com/08514127f48070a0b8c0f32d9568d361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to implement a single  `if` - `elif` - `else` statement and to simplify the code:

```py
def draw(self):
    self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)

    if self.direction == "right":
        image_list = self.rights
    elif self.direction == "standright":
        image_list = self.standingright
    elif self.direction == "left":
        image_list = self.lefts
    else:
        image_list = self.standingleft

    if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
        self.anim_index = 0
    player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]
    self.anim_index += 1
```

Anyway the issue is the code which sets `playerman.direction`. Note the direction `"left"` is set, but it is overwritten by `"standright"` immediately:

> ```py
> keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
> if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
>    playerman.direction = "left"
>    # [...]
>
> playerman.direction = "standright"
> ```

Set `playerman.direction` if a key is pressed and switch to `"standright"` or `"standleft"` if no key is pressed:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    playerman.direction = "left"
    # [...]

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    playerman.direction = "right"
    # [...]

else:
    if playerman.direction == "left":
        playerman.direction = "standleft"
    else:
        playerman.direction = "standright"
```

Comment: its good but the idk why this is happening [Video](https://gyazo.com/1ddcbe7f1d2bee1ef242507837b598aa) I am going left and its blitting its leftstanding instead of its left running I was messing around and still cant manage to fix it  [Script1](https://gyazo.com/75561efeba31d66379ba1d3f0ac5b206) [Script2](https://gyazo.com/8b56ae51d153888ac863fa8aa582dfac)

Comment: @HabibIsmail bacause you did not look at the answer carfully. It has to be `if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:` - `elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:` - `else:` focus on `elif`